# SQL how to join same value from one column table and then sum it

Tags: sql, postgresql

The problem here are I had a program that accept input like these

```
[
  {
    customer: 'Alexandra'
    productCode: 'SH20'
  },
  {
    customer: 'Alex'
    productCode: 'SH20'
  },
  {
    customer: 'Alexis'
    productCode: 'SH21'
  }
]
```

Every product code had their own price, table product are like these

```
{
  id: 1,
  productCode: 'SH20',
  name: 'Tires',
  price: 100
}
```

I want to sum up the total price of the product based on input, however using `WHERE IN ("SH20", "SH20", "SH21")` will only show 1 row from "SH20", If I sum it the total product price I get are wrong.

How do you select all row including duplicates using  SQL and sum it? Is this kind of problem can be solved using SQL only?

EDIT:

Attempted Query, lest assume that product `SH21` cost 200, and `SH20` 100. The total price on this query are 300, it should be 400 because there are 2 'SH20'.

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM product WHERE productCode in ('SH20', 'SH20', 'SH21')
```

Comment: I'm curious about `WHERE IN ("SH20", "SH20", "SH21")` .. Please post your attempted query.

Comment: Edited @FaNo_FN I add some explanation and example.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: I'm still confused with `..productCode IN ("SH20", "SH20", "SH21")`.. isn't `SH20` being repeated twice? Shouldn't it be just `..productCode IN ("SH20", "SH21")`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, I also change the title now to match my answered question. If you tried the answer below it will print the correct result. I should use `JOIN` not `WHERE IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the product table with your input data in order to get product SH20 twice.

```
SELECT SUM(product.price) AS total
FROM product 
JOIN
(
  SELECT 'SH20' AS productcode
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SH20' AS productcode
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SH21' AS productcode
) requested ON requested.productcode = product.productcode;
```

Thanks for accepting this :-) Here is the same with a `VALUES` clause for an alternative:

```
SELECT SUM(product.price) AS total
FROM product 
JOIN (VALUES ('SH20'), ('SH20'), ('SH21')) AS requested(productcode)
  ON requested.productcode = product.productcode;
```

Comment: Wow the later answer are faster than the first. Thanks a lot! Definitely learn some usage of SQL Join.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you need to use GROUP BY.

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM product WHERE productCode in ("SH20", "SH20", "SH21") GROUP BY productCode
```

If this is the behaviour you're looking for, I'd encourage you to read the manual page on group by and get familiar with it - it's a pattern you'll use a lot and well worth learning.